# Cpoying from PDF to Android Studio (Characters encoding issues)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, character-encoding

I have a list of words in Icelandic characters saved in a PDF file, what I want to achieve is copying those words and pasting the in an array in a JAVA class, the problem that I encountered is whenever I copy Android Studio do not recognize the special characters, the current method is to encode each word manually (by doing so : `list.add("\u266b")`) but it takes a lots of time, is there any other way ?

Comment: Does the font's ToUnicode (or specific encoding) correspond to the correct characters? When you copy text out of that PDF and paste it elsewhere, does it appear correct?

Comment: when I copy a word that contains a special character ( example : "ý") it appears like this : "y/"